# How to iterate through a list of nodes which might have sub-lists of nodes (unknown depth levels)

Tags: java, list, java-stream, tree-traversal

I have a list of nodes, and each node might have a list of subNodes (the number of levels are unknown):

```
class Node {
    int score;
    boolean selected;
    List<Node> subNodes;
}
```

Here's how an hypothetical structure might look like:

```
NODE
  + NODE
      + NODE
      + NODE
          + NODE
      + NODE
  + NODE
      + NODE
          + NODE
          + NODE
              + NODE
              + NODE
```

Combinations are just countless. I need a way to sum `NODE.score` for all those nodes that have `NODE.selected` set to `true`, possibly using Java 8 features. Any hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a nice use case for recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Judging by the structure, you've provided each `Node` in your `List` is the *root* of an *`N`-ary Tree* data structure (I assume that there are no circles).

And in order to get the required data, we can utilize one of the classic [*tree-traversal* algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). In case when the average depth is lower than the average width *Depth first search* algorithm would be more suitable because it would be more space-efficient, in the opposite situation it would be better to use *Breadth first search*. I'll go with DFS.

It's easier to come up with a recursive implementation, so I'll start with it. But it has **no** practical value in Java, hence we would proceed with a couple of improvements.

## Streams + recursion

You can create a helper-method responsible for flattening the nodes which would be called from the stream.

```
List<Node> nodes = // initializing the list
        
long totalScore = nodes.stream()
    .flatMap(node -> flatten(node).stream())
    .filter(Node::isSelected)
    .mapToLong(Node::getScore)
    .sum();
```

Recursive auxiliary method:

```
public static List<Node> flatten(Node node) {
    if (node.getSubNodes().isEmpty()) {
        return List.of(node);
    }
    
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(node);
    node.getSubNodes().forEach(n -> result.addAll(flatten(n)));
    return result;
}
```

## No recursion

To avoid `StackOverflowError` method `flatten()` can be implemented **without** recursion by polling and allocating new *nodes* on the stack (represented by an `ArrayDeque`) iterativelly.

```
public static List<Node> flatten(Node node) {
    
    List<Node> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Deque<Node> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    stack.add(node);
    
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = stack.poll();
        result.add(current);

        current.getSubNodes().forEach(stack::push);
    }
    return result;
}
```

## No recursion & No intermediate data allocation

Allocating intermediate data in the form of *nodes* which eventually would not be used is impractical.

Instead, we can make the auxiliary method to be responsible for calculating the *total score* produced by summarizing the score of each *selected node* in the *tree of nodes*.

For that we need to perform `isSelected()` while traversing the tree.

```
List<Node> nodes = // initializing the list
        
long totalScore = nodes.stream()
    .mapToLong(node -> getScore(node))
    .sum();
```

```
public static long getScore(Node node) {
    long total = 0;
    
    Deque<Node> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    stack.push(node);
    
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = stack.poll();
        if (current.isSelected()) total += current.getScore();

        current.getSubNodes().forEach(stack::push);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
public int recursiveTotal(final Node node) {
    //node not select, don't count the node or any of its subnodes
    if (!node.selected) {
        return 0;
    }
    //no subnodes, only node score counts
    if (node.subNodes.isEmpty()) {
        return node.score;
    }
    //node has subnodes, recursively count subnode score + parent node score
    int totalScore = node.score;
    for (final Node subNode : node.subNodes) {
        totalScore += recursiveTotal(subNode);
    }
    return totalScore;
}
```

Coded using stackoverflow as an IDE, no guarantee against compilation errors ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a recursive method in your Node class which returns a stream of nodes concatenating a stream of the parent node and the sub nodes:

```
class Node {
    int score;
    boolean selected;
    List<Node> subNodes;

    public Stream<Node> streamNodes() {
        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), subNodes.stream().flatMap(Node::streamNodes));
    }
}
```

and use it like below to stream over your list:

```
List<Node> myNodes = //your list
int sum = myNodes.stream()
                 .flatMap(Node::streamNodes)
                 .filter(Node::isSelected)
                 .mapToInt(Node::getScore)
                 .sum();
```